# How to connect Dell Boomi with SAP?

Tags: idoc, boomi

Dell Boomi needs a lot of information for the SAP connector shape. There are a lot of fields to be filled for the Connection Setting AND Listener settings.

I only have our SAP server's system id, instance number, username, password and server location.

How can I fill the rest? What are any extra steps needed to do the integration?

When I try to test the connection with the only information I have, I get following error:

> Test execution of SAPconnectionP completed with errors. Embedded
> message: Severe errors occurred during start shape execution,
> terminating process.; Caused by: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or
> illegal XML character is specified.

I have already copied the SAP jar files to the lib folder.

Comment: `How can I fill the rest?` what are you missing? show how you call the connector

Comment: Did you read the boomi official document for [SAP connector](https://help.boomi.com/bundle/connectors/page/r-atm-SAP_Connector_1357073d-338b-4c1c-b475-01197756f04a.html) & [SAP connection](https://help.boomi.com/bundle/connectors/page/r-atm-SAP_Connection_77ed713f-8903-44f9-8b67-deee5da578cf.html)?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did read that. I know where the problem may be. I am no SAP administrator and I need to the do the Additional SAP and database setup to receive IDocs. The whole set up with ALE ports and logical systems. I have no idea how to do that tough.